# Can not access computer on Windows network (0x80070035 The network path was not found)

Tags: windows-7, networking, netbios

Computer "A" and "B": Win 7 Ultimate x64, Kaspersky Internet Security 2015, Windows Firewall turned off, UAC turned off, users are Admins.
Asus RT-N12D1 WiFi router: Firewall and DoS protection turned off.
"A" & "B" ping each other and itself. Networks are Home type.
Network Discovery, File Sharing — on.
"A" is connected to the router via cable.
"B" — via WiFi.
"A" & "B" are visible in the networks of each other.
"Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only" — disabled.
I can access "A" from "B".
————————————
Edit:
I uninstalled 6to4 Adapter from "A" (there was none on "B"). This didn't helped.

**The problem: I can not access "B" from "A".** (0x80070035 The network path was not found)

Comment: Have you checked for a feature called "WiFi Client Isolation" (or similar) on your router?

Comment: I have "Set AP Isolated" option and it's set to "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper disabled on "A". So re-enabling it solved the problem.