# Can not access Network Share by IP Address - Error 0x80070035

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, network-shares

I have a desktop & laptop (both having Windows 7 SP1 32 & part of WORKGROUP) that are connected to my router DIR 615. Desktop has DHCP Reserved IP as 192.168.0.100.

From my laptop I can Ping, Tracert and RDP to my desktop using IP4 address. However when I type \\192.168.0.100\test (folder test is shared on desktop)  in Start --> Run prompt to access my desktop as network share it does not work. Error Code 0x80070035 Ironically it works well for IP6 Link Local Address!

I am unable to understand why it does not work with IP4 address. I have tried the following

1. Completely disable Comodo & Windows Firewall including its service on desktop & laptop
2. Disable IP6 in network adapters (both desktop as well as laptop)
3. Uninstall and reinstall network adapters on laptop & desktop
4. Tried other way from desktop to laptop as well, same issue.
5. File & Printer Sharing is enabled in Network Adapter properties
6. Firewall in Router is set to lowest security settings
7. Enable Netbios over TCP/IP in IPv4 Advanced properties
8. It only works on the same machine though i.e. from desktop itself I can access \\192.168.0.100\Test
9. Services running on both computers are Computer Browser, RPC, TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper

I am not sure if I am missing any specific service that should be running on desktop or may be some setting in router but then with IP6 it was working anyway.

There are similar threads on this Superuser forum as well e.g. [Thread1](https://superuser.com/questions/823121/can-not-access-computer-on-windows-network-0x80070035-the-network-path-was-not) & [Thread2](https://superuser.com/questions/906472/unable-to-connect-to-windows-computer-for-file-sharing) but those solution did not work in my case.

Please help me in troubleshooting this issue. Thanks.

IPCONFIG Command Details
Desktop

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : AMD260
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a174:cc02:47c6:d473%24(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, September 15, --------------
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, September 22, --------------
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : ----------
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6056:aac2:b59c:829%19(Preferred) 
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.8.41(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : ----------
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7170:d36c:34a8:20b2%20(Preferred) 
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.32.178(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : ----------
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{122020E7-DE96-4CE2-9261-BD61B9CE7A9D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A1795D97-7AC8-417A-A694-26314761A801}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6A2D2665-9E2C-45E0-8994-776918AFD826}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5EE21AC0-3394-4AAD-A978-7B4396058008}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

IPCONFIG Laptop

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : VAIO
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4c0:5fcc:c5dc:5622%22(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, September 15, -----------
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, September 21, ----------
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : -------------
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : ------------------
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c86f:ce9f:6c72:95c3%14(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.61.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : -----------
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : ----------------------
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ---------------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad7c:5d08:803b:44f7%15(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.18.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : ----------
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : ---------------------
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E1B151C1-A17A-4ADA-8F7C-B2AB4B9027D4}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{DBAD98BE-DDCF-4706-A5EA-56E29626852F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BF13CDE8-35D4-4B8E-92C2-57D82FF49EA1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0A231D9B-B5F1-4F06-960B-BCDC7D35898C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Command `netsh advfirewall show allprofiles` returns on both desktop & laptop

> An error occurred while attempting to contact the  Windows Firewall
>   service. Make  sure that the service is running and try your request
>   again.

[image]

Comment: Post ipconfig /all from laptop and desktop.

Comment: Along with `ipconfig /all` from each machine, also post the output from `netsh advfirewall show allprofiles` on each machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Windows Server 2016, and resolved it by:

1. *unticking* the "File & Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" item on the Network Adapter properties (found in the Network & Sharing Centre),
2. rebooting,
3. *ticking* it again,
4. and finally rebooting a second time.